# Found array with dim 4. Estimator expected <= 2

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn

I have 94 images that 700x500px, and the images name is like 0_70.jpg, 0 is the label.

split the training and test data and try to fit it for training, it got the issue for dim 4, i tried to reshape the matrices and it doesn't help.

```
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = []
y = []


for filename in glob.iglob("images/" + '**/*.jpg', recursive=True):
    #print(filename)
    path = filename.split('_')[0]
    label = path.split('/')[1]
    y.append(label)
    img = plt.imread(filename)
    X.append(img)
    
    
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3)

import numpy

Xtrain = numpy.array(X_train)
Xtest = numpy.array(X_test)

ytrain = numpy.array(y_train)
ytest = numpy.array(y_test)

print(Xtrain.shape)
print(Xtest.shape)
print(ytrain.shape)
print(ytest.shape)

#(65, 500, 700, 3)
#(29, 500, 700, 3)
#(65,)
#(29,)

#xx=Xtrain.reshape(1,-1)

#print(xx.shape)

# nsamples, nx, ny, three = Xtrain.shape
# d2_train_dataset = train_dataset.reshape((nsamples,nx*ny))


from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reshape like this for matrices:

```
nsamples, nx, ny, three = Xtrain.shape
d2_train_dataset = Xtrain.reshape(nsamples,-1)
```